# Is $\det(ABA)= \det(B)$?

Tags: matrices

For two square matrices $A$ and $B$.

$A$ is invertible, and $\det(ABA)=0$.

So then, $\det(B)=0$.

Is it true or false?

My answer is false.

$\det(ABA^{-1})$ is equal to $\det(B)$

But $A \neq A^{-1}$

So, my answer is this statement is false.

I just wanted to know is my answer correct or not.

Comment: If A=$3\mathbb{I}$, $\det(ABA)=9^n\det(B)$. It definitely is not true.

Comment: Sorry, but your wording is of a poor quality and there are typos. Try and improve.

Comment: By the way, for square matrices $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and for an invertible matrix, $\det(A^{-1})=(\det(A))^{-1}$.

Comment: What we can say is, if $\det(ABA)=0$, then since $\det(PQ)=\det(P)\det(Q)$ for any same-sized square matrices $P$ and $Q$, $\det(A)^2\det(B)=0$. Also since $A$ is invertible, $\det(A)\ne0$, so we can conclude $\det(B) =0$. Of course $\det(ABA)=\det(B)$ is not true in general.

Comment: I tried to edit your post to be more clear and well-typed in $\TeX$, but i was not sure if i fully understood you question. Please improve the question by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There  are matrices $A$ such that $A=A^{-1}$. More generally if $\det  A=\pm 1$ then $\det(ABA)=\det B$  for every $B$ (in  fact the last statement is "if and only if")..

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$ is invertable we know that it is a square matrix and that its determinant is not equal to zero.

For square matrices we have

$$\det(ABA)=\det A \det B \det A=0$$
We know that $\det A \neq 0$, hence we can conclude that $\det B = 0$. The last statement implies that $B$ is not invertable$.

Comment: Thank you so much.